# More than meets the eye

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, wordplay, story, cryptic-clues

A friend of mine is an artist, and painted this for me. She told me that "there's more than meets the eye," whatever that could mean. I suppose it makes for a nice painting, though.

[image: A fox leaping over a dog]

**What am I?**

Hint:

> I posted this on PSE because it was just *two cryptic* for me to solve.

Hint 2:

> The clue Hexomino deciphered is not a red herring. It's a necessary part of the puzzle.

Hint 3:

> The entire decoded message acts as a single cryptic clue.

Comment: rot13 Lbh'er gur nycunorg ;)

Comment: rot13 - Ybbxf yvxr n cnatenz gb zr.. ;-)

Comment: rot13 - Vf vg fnsr gb nffhzr gung gur frpbaq uvqqra grkg gung pna or eryriryrq jvgu fbzr vzntr znavchyngvba ("Gur dhvpx oebja sbk"...) vf whfg na negvsnpg bs ubj lbh cebqhprq gur vzntr?

Comment: @DBS Hexomino has discovered all that is needed to finish the puzzle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hexomino has solved the code and PDT has revived the question by trying to solve the resulting plaintext.

Based on recent hints and on a comment by the OP, I think the overall answer is:

> **[BS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bullshit)**!
>
>  The decoded phrase "Basic substitution, for beginners? Fat chance" is a cryptic clue. The last hint confinrms that and also tells us the enumeration: (2).
>
>  The wordplay is "basic substitution, for beginners" and tells us to take the "beginners" of **B**(asic) **S**(ubstitution). The definition is "Fat chance", which, like BS, can be used on its own to mean: No, that's nonsense.

Comment: In fact, if you look at hint #1, you'll see that rot13("gjb pelcgvp" jnf zrnag gb vaqvpngr gur fbyhgvba erdhverq fbyivat n pelcgvp pyhr jvgu na nafjre yratgu bs gjb).

Answer (score 14):

**Partial answer**

First Step

> Write out the [pangram associated to the picture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_quick_brown_fox_jumps_over_the_lazy_dog).
>  **THE QUICK BROWN FOX JUMPS OVER THE LAZY DOG**.

Second step

> Remove any letter that appears for a second time or more.
>  **THEQUICKBROWNFXJMPSVLAZYDG**

Third step

> Associate each letter in the above sequence to the corresponding letter of the alphabet that appears in that position to create a substitution cipher, so $$T \rightarrow A, H \rightarrow B, E \rightarrow C, Q \rightarrow D,\ldots  $$

Fourth step

> Use this cipher to decrypt the faded text in the image
>  **Htsbe slhsvbvlvbxf, ixp hucbffups? Itv ektfeu**
>  becomes
>  **Basic substitution, for beginners? Fat chance**

At this point, given the message, I may have hit a red herring but it might start others in the right direction.
My guess is that

> We must decrypt the same text but using a different cipher.

Comment: I guess Rot13(Znl or gurl ner gjb frcnengr pyhrf. 1. Onfvp fhofgvghgvba sbe ortvaaref? 2. Sng punapr.)

Comment: @Techidiot yes, you are probably right given the hint. Although I'm not sure on the answer to either currently

Comment: The hint makes me think rot13(gung vg'f n pelcgvp pebffjbeq glcr pyhr. Gur BC unf znqr chmmyrf srnghevat gurz orsber.)

Comment: interesting. By the way, rot13(gur cnatenz vf rira vapyhqrq nf grkg va gur vzntr vs lbh hc gur pbagenfg. )

Comment: Haha, I am a complete beginner and got the same answer without your hints. Found the same red herring :-)

Answer (score 6):

A little edit: Building from Hexomino’s answer, you are

> **GL(short for good luck)**!

Why

> The final message ‘Basic substitution, for beginners? Fat chance’ is a cryptic clue.

> Ok so doing some research I found that GLbasic is a programming language. So how does this make us reinterpret the cryptic clue well I think the op meant something like __Basic, substitution for beginner’s fat chance. ‘Beginners fat chance’ refers to Good Luck and its substitution is GL. This then makes GLbasic?

The title:

> I think it is just hinting to the fact that the pangram under the encoded message is only visible with some editing done to the picture.

Comment: That's very close, but not quite! I added a third hint to the post.

Comment: How about rot13(onq yhpx, qhr gb gur 13 sebz ebg-13 orvat pbafvqrerq hayhpxl; 'onq yhpx' naq 'sng punapr' ner flabalzf...)?

Comment: @PDT Almost! rot13(Gur nafjre jvyy or gjb yrggref ybat).

Comment: Did I get it right now I edited it 12 hours ago?

Comment: @PDT: Blue Herring is from Mars; answers may take a while. Anyway, rot13(gur bayl unys-ernfbanoyr gjb-yrggre nafjre V pna znxr sebz gur pelcgvp vf OF: O(nfvp) F(hafgvghgvba) sbe ortvaaref. Gur qrs vf "sng punapr" nf va: "Vf gur nafjre gb guvf Yhgrgvhz? OF/Sng punapr". V'z abg fhcre pbaivprq. Jul jbhyq nalbar znxr fhpu na rynobengr cnvagvat sbe gung? Naq jurer'f gur pbarpgvba gb "zber guna zrrgf gur rlr?").

Comment: @MOehm You're right on the dot with that!

Comment: Yeah I give up if none of my attempts are right.

Comment: My answer as Lu or Gl isn’t the answer it seems… M Oehm put your answer up as BS and see what happens?